# How to change bool value of is_actual (DRF)

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have two fields in `Post` model -

```
def next_month():
    now = timezone.now()
    return now + relativedelta(months=+1)

created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
end_time = models.DateTimeField(default=next_month, blank=True, editable=False)
```

So, I want to add field `is_actual = models.BooleanField()`. If end_time > now(), value equal True.
I understand, that I'm need to use some function, when function runs at 00:00 every day, for checking date and change is_actual value. But I don't know how to do that. Can you help me, please?

Comment: i dont think you need a field you can just do `def is_actual(): return end_time > timezone.now()` when you have a instance you can do the check. `instance.is_actual()` will return a boolean value.

Comment: To continue with @KapilManiLamichhane, you specifically want to do this: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield

Answer (score 0):

You may introduce a `is_actual` property into the model.

```py
from django.utils.timezone import now


class Post():

  created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  end_time = models.DateTimeField(default=next_month, blank=True, editable=False)

  @property
  def is_actual(self):
    return bool(self.end_time and self.end_time > now())
```

Comment: With this implementation, I can't use filter, where is_actual == true.

Comment: So, my main problem is using filter with is_actual field.

Comment: Unfortunately filter is performed at database level, hence property approach will not be ideal for your case. It will be good for you to rephrase your question so that we can provide an appropriate answer to your problem.

Comment: If you don't mind using list comprehension to perform an additional step, property will still be a simple, generic and straightforward approach. Setting `is_actual` as a column in a database table maybe overkill, and introduce unnecessary window of opportunity to derive wrong answer, as we need a cron to update it.